# Create a for loop that receives information from an array and adds it to my template card component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, for-loop

I have a reactjs + typescript component which shows templates:

I wanted to pass the template details such as title, description and image with an array.

```
import ActionPageTemplateContainer, { Template } from "./ActionPageTemplateContainer";


type Props = {
    onOnboardingComplete: Function;
};

let templates: Template[];

// TODO: make sure this is tree shaked once Meteor implements that feature.
if (Meteor.isProduction) {
    templates = [];
} else {
    templates = [
        {
            title: "Groceries",
            description: "blablabalblabla",
            imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753993/groceries.png",
        },
    ];
}
```

```
    <ActionPageTemplateContainer templates={templates} />
```

In my ActionPageTemplateContainer I used to have a container with my template cards, but now I need to do a loop so that each template card recieves info from my array, how can I do this?

My ActionPageTemplateContainer looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
// import TemplateCard from "/imports/cuadds/client/components/modals/templates/TemplateCard";
import styles from "./styles/actionpage.m.css";

// const groceries = "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753993/groceries.png";
// const shopping = "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753766/shopping.png";
// const travel = "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753885/travel.png";
// const description = "Description of what this things does so the reader can have info of";

export type Template = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    imgURL?: string;
};

type Props = {
    templates?: Template[];
};

const ActionPageTemplateContainer = ({ templates }: Props) => {
    const children = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
        const template = 
    }

    return <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>{children}</div>;

    // return (
    //  <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
    //      <TemplateCard
    //          title={"Grocery List"}
    //          description={description}
    //          img={groceries}
    //          classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
    //      />
    //      <TemplateCard
    //          title={"Shopping Space"}
    //          description={description}
    //          img={shopping}
    //          classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
    //      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over the `templates` array

```
const ActionPageTemplateContainer = ({ templates }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
      {templates.map((item) => (
        <TemplateCard
          title={item.title}
          description={item.description}
          img={item.imgURL}
          classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Be sure to check that templates is an array or else you'll get an exception when trying to use map.